# Cumulative count reset on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                 'col2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                 'col3': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                 'desired': [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]})
```

I want to apply a rolling sum on `col3` which resets when either of `col1` or `col2` changes, or when the previous value of `col3` was zero.

Note that the count is offset by 1 cell. This means the desired value for a new `(col1, col2)` combination will always be zero.

The code below demonstrates the required logic. However, it takes nearly 4 minutes on the dataset below.

```
des = []
count = 0
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    des.append(count)
    if (df.iloc[i-1].col1 == df.iloc[i].col1) & \
       (df.iloc[i-1].col2 == df.iloc[i].col2) & \
       (df.iloc[i-1].col3 == 1):
    
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 0
    
des.append(0)

df['desired'] = des
```

A bigger dataset to test on: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbafcq6hdkh4r9r/test.csv?dl=0

Comment: Can you add the case when first row of col3 is 0. And no images please hard to copy.

Comment: note: the last `desired` value in your example should be `1`. That is also what I understand it should be based on your explanation. But the code you give to demonstrate the logic gives `0`. I suspect you should change to `des.append(count)` after your loop.

Comment: It is also unclear whether you want the cumulative sum of `col3` or the cumulative count (where nonzero). The two are the same for `col3 in {0, 1}`, but what about other values?  The problem statement indicates `sum`, but the example code suggests `count`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `groupby` with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) first and then count consecutive `1`:

```
a = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].shift().fillna(0).eq(1)
b = a.cumsum()

df['desired'] = b-b.where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)

print (df.head(20))
      col1  col2  col3  desired
0   100055     1     1        0
1   100055     1     0        1
2   100055     1     0        0
3   100055     1     0        0
4   100055     1     0        0
5   100055     1     0        0
6   100055     1     0        0
7   100055     1     0        0
8   100055     1     0        0
9   100055     1     0        0
10  100055     1     1        0
11  100055     1     1        1
12  100055     1     0        2
13  100055     1     1        0
14  100055     1     1        1
15  100055     1     0        2
16  100055     1     0        0
17  100055     1     1        0
18  100055     1     0        1
19  100055     1     1        0
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't quite work because the desired column doesn't get reset back to 1 after col3 becomes zero within the same (col1, col2) pair.  I will post a bigger dataset.

Comment: Can you changaed your sample data by your big df? I think your question is really complicated, so [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really necessary. Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael I've added code which works which I hope demonstrates the logic I need.

Comment: Please check edited answer, I test output and it is same like your loop solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP wants a **rolling** count, that seems to indicate that they want to handle groups that may repeat at different places in the `df`, without lumping them all together (like a `groupby` would do).

From the problem statement, it sounds more like a cumulative operation with resets. That is a class of problems that is relatively easy to vectorize, and it doesn't involve `groupby` at all.

Here is a way using `numpy`:

```
def cum_count(df, groupcols, zerocol):
    a = df[groupcols].values
    c = df[zerocol].values
    # find indices to reset the cumulative count
    r0 = np.concatenate(([True], np.any(a[1:] != a[:-1], axis=1)))
    r1 = np.concatenate(([True], c[:-1] == 0))
    reset = np.nonzero(r0 + r1)[0]
    # offset: values to subtract at reset indices
    off = np.concatenate(([0], np.diff(reset)))
    # we add 1 everywhere except at reset indices
    delt = np.ones(df.shape[0], dtype=int)
    delt[reset] -= off

    return np.cumsum(delt) - 1
```

And here are a corner case example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 1, 1, 0],
    ['a', 1, 1, 1],
    ['a', 1, 1, 2],
    ['b', 1, 1, 0],
    ['b', 1, 1, 1],
    ['b', 1, 1, 2],
    ['a', 1, 1, 0],
    ['a', 1, 1, 1],
    ['a', 1, 1, 2],
], columns='col1 col2 col3 desired'.split())

c = custom_cum_count(df, 'col1 col2'.split(), 'col3')
assert np.all(c == df['desired'])
print(c)

# out
[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
```