# Cumulative Count with Specific Condition in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

I have a organizational dataset with multiple years per organization. I have looked at a lot of cumulative sum and groupby answers on StackOverflow and can't seem to find one that fits my situation.

I am interested in counting the cumulative number of years each organization has had a NEW active program. The program is indicated by values of '1' in the column *Program*. What I want to get is the new column *Years_NEW_Program* shown below.

```
OrgID   Year    Program     Years_NEW_Program       event_window
3128    2015    0           0                       -2
3128    2016    0           0                       -1
3128    2017    1           1                       0
3128    2018    1           2                       1
11502   2015    1           0                       
11502   2016    1           0
31530   2009    0           0                       -2  
31530   2010    0           0                       -1
31530   2011    1           1                       0   
31530   2012    1           2                       1   
31530   2013    1           3                       2   
31530   2014    0           0
99      2014    1           0     
99      2015    0           0
99      2016    1           0   
99      2017    0           0
99      2018    0           0
```

What makes it unique is that I only want the 'count' to start when an organization has NOT had the program in prior years (as indicated by '0' under *Program*), and then implements it (as indicated by '1' under *Program*). I also want to only start the count if the organization has had *at least two years* worth of '0's *before* starting the program and keeps the program for at least two years -- this is why ID 99 above does not receive a count.

*Ideally*, I would also be able to get a column like that in *event_window* for organizations that get non-zero values in *Years_NEW_Program*. But if need be I could work with just *Years_NEW_Program.*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why is 2014 for org 31530 0 and not 4?

Comment: Because the value for *Program* is 0. That means the program was not active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (admittedly lengthy) way to do this.
First, make a separate dataframe of each OrgID, that makes it easier to process. Later, you concat them back together.
For each of those dataframes, create a "startCounter" and "stopCounter" based on your condition. And then add a column "counting", which should represent when the counter should be on.
There is a function that calculates the cumulative sum with a reset, and you should be fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

def cumsumWithReset(df):
    # Make the cumulative sum of the column "counting"
    # When the value of "counting" is zero, then reset the cumulative sum
    prevVal = 0
    df["cumsum"] = 0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cumsum = row["counting"] + prevVal
        if row['counting'] == 0:
            cumsum = 0
        prevVal = cumsum
        df.loc[index, 'cumsum'] = cumsum
    return df


df = df.sort_values(by="OrgID", ascending = True)
orgList = df.OrgID.drop_duplicates()
dfList = []
for org in orgList:
    dfOrg = df[df["OrgID"] == org]
    dfOrg = dfOrg.sort_values(by="Year", ascending = True).reset_index(drop=True)
    dfOrg['program1Ybefore'] = dfOrg["Program"].shift(periods=1, fill_value = 1)
    dfOrg['program2Ybefore'] = dfOrg["Program"].shift(2, fill_value = 1)
    dfOrg['startCounter'] = (dfOrg['program1Ybefore'] == 0) & (dfOrg['program2Ybefore'] == 0) & (dfOrg['Program'] == 1)
    dfOrg['stopCounter'] =  dfOrg["Program"] == 0
    dfOrg['counting'] =  np.where(dfOrg['startCounter'] & ~dfOrg['stopCounter'],1,np.NaN)
    dfOrg['counting'] =  np.where(dfOrg['stopCounter'],0,dfOrg['counting'])
    dfOrg['counting'] =  dfOrg['counting'].ffill(axis = 0).fillna(0) 
    dfOrg = cumsumWithReset(dfOrg)
    dfList.append(dfOrg)

dfResult = pd.concat(dfList).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**EDIT for large df:**
Do not loop over separate dataframes for each organisation, but create a different flag that keeps track of changing organisations.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["OrgID", "Year"], ascending = [True, True])
df["newOrg"] = df["OrgID"] != df["OrgID"].shift(1)
df["newOrgShift"] = df["newOrg"].shift(1, fill_value = True)

df['program1Ybefore'] = df["Program"].shift(periods=1, fill_value = 1)
df['program1Ybefore'] = np.where(df["newOrg"],1,df['program1Ybefore'])
df['program2Ybefore'] = df["Program"].shift(2, fill_value = 1)
df['program2Ybefore'] = np.where((df["newOrg"]) | (df["newOrgShift"]) ,1,df['program2Ybefore'])


df['startCounter'] = (df['program1Ybefore'] == 0) & (df['program2Ybefore'] == 0) & (df['Program'] == 1)
df['stopCounter'] =  (df["Program"] == 0) | (df["newOrg"])
df['counting'] =  np.where(df['startCounter'] & ~df['stopCounter'],1,np.NaN)
df['counting'] =  np.where(df['stopCounter'],0,df['counting'])
df['counting'] =  df['counting'].ffill(axis = 0).fillna(0) 

df = cumsumWithReset(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work! There are ~1 million rows, though, so I've only tried it on a sample. Do you have any thoughts on how this could be applied without the loop?

Comment: Edited it for large dataframes. Although less readable, it should be faster

Comment: I've accepted this answer. It worked well and I really appreciate you taking the time to contribute. Your solution inspired me to work on it a bit more, so below I've provided an alternative that tweaks a few things from your solution. But, again, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

@braml1's answer works but here I'm provided an alternative that tweaks a few things. First, here's the alternative solution:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['OrgID', 'Year'], ascending = True)
df['startCounter'] = df.groupby('OrgID')['Program'].apply(lambda x: 
                          ((x.shift(1)==0)&(x.shift(2) == 0) & (x == 1))).values
df['stopCounter'] = df.groupby('OrgID')['Total_Fees_for_Services_binary'].apply(lambda x: x==0).values
df['counting'] = np.where(df['startCounter'] & ~df['stopCounter'],1,np.NaN)
df['counting'] = np.where(df['stopCounter'], 0, df['counting'])
df['counting'] = df.groupby('OrgID')['counting'].ffill().fillna(0) 
a = df.groupby('OrgID')['counting'].fillna(0).eq(1)
b = a.cumsum()
df['cumsum'] = b-b.where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Here are the key differences. First, I sort by *OrgID* and *Year*:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['OrgID', 'Year'], ascending = True)
```

Then with *startCounter* and *stopCounter* I differ by incorporating *groupby* statements:

```
df['startCounter'] = df.groupby('OrgID')['Program'].apply(lambda x: 
                      ((x.shift(1)==0)&(x.shift(2) == 0) & (x == 1))).values
df['stopCounter'] = df.groupby('OrgID)['Total_Fees_for_Services_binary'].apply(lambda x: x==0).values
```

With these commands I can skip creating the two-step intermediate variables *program1Ybefore* and *program2Ybefore*.

Next, the first two lines in the creation of the *counting* variable are the same as in @braml1's answer:

```
df['counting'] = np.where(df['startCounter'] & ~df['stopCounter'],1,np.NaN)
df['counting'] = np.where(df['stopCounter'], 0, df['counting'])
```

The third line, though, again incorporates *groupby*:

```
df['counting'] = df.groupby('OrgID')['counting'].ffill().fillna(0)
```

The biggest change, though, comes in the final step, creating the *cumsum* variable. Here I was inspired by a different [S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504138/cumulative-sum-reset-on-condition)

Specifically, instead of applying @braml1's *cumsumWithReset* function (which uses a loop over all the rows of the dataframe), I apply a cumulative sum with resetting upon a specific condition being met. First, *a* converts the binary (0/1) column *counting* into a True/False column. The *counting* column, to recap, is the column that indicates all rows where there is a valid 'new program' -- and it is for these rows that we want a cumulative sum.

```
a = df.groupby('OrgID')['counting'].fillna(0).eq(1)
```

*b* then takes the cumulative sum for the values in *a*

```
b = a.cumsum()
```

Lastly, we assign values to the new variable *cumsum*, with the values being *b* where condition *a* holds, and zero otherwise (and then forward fill the column with zeros until we find *a* again):

```
df['cumsum'] = b-b.where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

It is this last step that really helps performance. By not doing the *iterrows* that's in the *cumsumWithReset* function, we can really speed up the performance -- especially with a large dataset.

Again, though, thanks to @braml1 for the help. Your solution worked! My alternative solution is just some incremental improvements.