# Count of Contiguously Preceding Rows with Specific Value within Time Window in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

really struggling with this pandas task for a research project.

I have a dataframe `df` that has two columns: `time` (a datetime column) and `result` (a boolean column). I want to count the streak of TRUE rows immediately preceding the current row with a look-back window of 7 days.

For example: 
If the preceding row is false, then the count is 0 
If the preceding row is true, then I want to know what the streak of true rows was within the 7 day period preceding that row.

Example of expected output below.

| time | result | DESIRED OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/1/21 | TRUE | 0 (no preceding rows) |
| 5/6/21 | TRUE | 1 |
| 5/8/21 | FALSE | 2 (immediately preceded by streak of 2 TRUE rows in past 7 days) |
| 5/10/21 | FALSE | 0 |
| 5/11/21 | TRUE | 0 |
| 5/14/21 | TRUE | 1 (preceding row is TRUE) |
| 5/20/21 | TRUE | 1 (immediately preceded by streak of one TRUE rows in 1 week window) |
| 5/21/21 | TRUE | 2 (immediately preceded by streak of two TRUE rows in 1 week window) |
| 5/22/21 | TRUE | 2 (immediately preceded by streak of two TRUE rows in 1 week window) |
| 5/23/21 | FALSE | 3 (immediately preceded by streak of three TRUE rows in 1 week window) |
| 5/24/21 | TRUE | 0 (preceded by FALSE row) |
| 5/26/21 | TRUE | 1 (immediately preceded by streak of 1 TRUE row) |

I have been scouring Stack Overflow and racking my brain for days but just can't figure out a way to do this well. The trick with shift and groupby, e.g. `df * (df.groupby((df != df.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount())` would work perfectly except it doesn't take into account the 7-day lookback window and the data is sampled irregularly, so I can't make assumptions on how many rows appear there will be in a 7-day period.

Thank you all so much for your time and help!

Comment: Does any date repeat in your 'time' column?

Comment: No it does not. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were on the right track. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46504302/11588364) answers the concept of resetting the count on a certain condition. The extra piece I believe you're looking for in order to have the flexibility to group by week would look something like this:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='W')])['result'].count() # Simple Count Example
```

The frequency can be substituted by any one of the anchored offsets [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets)

Comment: Sorry I don't get how I would use this. Can you explain it a little more, please? I'm not sure I get how to combine this with the code I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fit the bill

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.array([['5/1/21', True, '0 (no preceding rows)'],
       ['5/6/21', True, '1'],
       ['5/8/21', False,
        '2 (immediately preceded by streak of 2 TRUE rows in past 7 days)'],
       ['5/10/21', False, '0'],
       ['5/11/21', True, '0'],
       ['5/14/21', True, '1 (preceding row is TRUE)'],
       ['5/20/21', True,
        '1 (immediately preceded by streak of one TRUE rows in 1 week window)'],
       ['5/21/21', True,
        '2 (immediately preceded by streak of two TRUE rows in 1 week window)'],
       ['5/22/21', True,
        '2 (immediately preceded by streak of two TRUE rows in 1 week window)'],
       ['5/23/21', False,
        '3 (immediately preceded by streak of three TRUE rows in 1 week window)'],
       ['5/24/21', True, '0 (preceded by FALSE row)'],
       ['5/26/21', True,
        '1 (immediately preceded by streak of 1 TRUE row)'],
       ['5/27/21', True,
        '2 (immediately preceded by streak of 2 TRUE row)']])
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['time','result','output_check'])

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index('time')
# i will note that this casting of the result to num shouldn't be necessary, 
# but something in my process is being wonky and I'm too lazy to sort why
# pandas is not willing atm to sum a boolean column
df['result_num'] = np.where(df['result'] == 'True', 1, 0)
df['result_num_vice'] = np.where(df['result'].shift(1) == 'False', 1, 0)
# each time that we hit a zero, we restart the counter so this is basically a 
# group, so lets use cum sum to create a counter that increases by 1 each time 
# we hit a zero. We can then use this counter as the id. 
df['id'] = df['result_num_vice'].transform('cumsum')

df['output'] = (
    df.groupby(['id'])['result_num'].apply(
        lambda x:x.rolling('8d', closed = 'right').sum()
    )
)

# each true row after the initial will include itself in the count, so lets just
# subtract one from each row with true 
df['output'] = np.where(
    (df['result_num'] == 1) & (df['output']>0), 
    df['output'] - 1,
    df['output']
)
df = df[['result','output_check','output']]
df
```

Output:

```
            result  output_check           output
time            
2021-05-01  True    0 (no preceding rows)   0.0
2021-05-06  True    1   1.0
2021-05-08  False   2 (immediately preceded by streak of 2 TRUE ro...   2.0
2021-05-10  False   0   0.0
2021-05-11  True    0   0.0
2021-05-14  True    1 (preceding row is TRUE)   1.0
2021-05-20  True    1 (immediately preceded by streak of one TRUE ...   1.0
2021-05-21  True    2 (immediately preceded by streak of two TRUE ...   2.0
2021-05-22  True    2 (immediately preceded by streak of two TRUE ...   2.0
2021-05-23  False   3 (immediately preceded by streak of three TRU...   3.0
2021-05-24  True    0 (preceded by FALSE row)   0.0
2021-05-26  True    1 (immediately preceded by streak of 1 TRUE row)    1.0
2021-05-27  True    2 (immediately preceded by streak of 2 TRUE row)    2.0
```

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for a rolling aggregate, I believe. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html is the documentation. Here is some code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(

[['5/1/21', True ],
['5/6/21',  True],
['5/8/21',  False],
['5/10/21',False],
['5/11/21'  ,True],
['5/14/21', True] ,
['5/20/21', True],
['5/21/21', True ],
['5/22/21', True],
['5/23/21', False ],
['5/24/21', True],
['5/26/21', True ]], columns=['date', 'result']
)

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.set_index('date')
rolling_result = df.result.rolling('7D').sum()
print(rolling_result)
```

and results
[image: results of runnning example code]

Please notice I converted your date column into a datetime index, which I think is required for this to work. You could always make a small, temporary dataframe to do this, if you don't want to convert the whole thing.

Using `sum()` works because summing a boolean column gives you the number of True values in it.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. The output column is what I want to achieve. My dataframe currently only has the date and result columns. Thank you for trying to answer my question. I appreciate your time and expertise! I have edited my original question so that the output column is called "DESIRED OUTPUT" to make that point more clear.

Comment: Ok - But I think my code still works. I will adjust the input dataframe, but the rolling will still do the job. The image I posted is my results.

Comment: I editied my input.

Comment: Thank you, Neha, for trying to help me. The output of your solution still doesn't get me what I need, but I appreciate the attempt. I don't want the sum of True rows in the 7 week window, but rather, the streak of contiguous TRUE rows immediately preceding the row confined to a 7-day look-back window. Sorry I know this is confusing and I am probably not describing it as clearly as it can be.